# update_user_meta not working

Tags: php

I have made a form. Users are able to make choices on this form. I want their choice to be saved on the database. I am trying to do this with `user_update_meta` but I am unable to make it work. I have tried several things.

I first tried the following:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

     $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); //get the current user
     $current_user->ID; //get the user id

     update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'user_login', 'Jimbo' );
}
```

Then I tried:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

  global $current_user;

  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); //get the user id

  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_login', 'Jimbo' );
}
```

All of my code:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "db_name";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM db_name;" );
//print_r($retrieve_data);
?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table>
<?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) { ?>
<tr>
     <th>Programma:</th><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $retrieved_data->name;?></td>
     <th><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Abonneer" /></th>
  </tr>
<?php 
}
//This is ment to insert the username and choice in the database. However, I want to use update_user_meta
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

  global $current_user;

  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); //get the user id

  wp_update_user( array(
    'ID'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'user_login' => 'Jimbo',
) );
}

?>
</table>
</form>
```

I do not know where I am going wrong. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I am using wp_get_current user because there are many users who can use this site and I cannot limit it to just one user id.

Comment: did you add ->  global $current_user;

Comment: Yes, but it will not change the name of Parsa237 to Jimbo. Do I also have to somehow give the table instead of only the column? I also used the code in your answer which gave a error.````Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function addMyCustomMeta()````. @StefanAvramovic

Comment: What hapens if you hard code values in update_user_meta( 1, 'user_login', 'Jimbo');

Comment: The thing is, in your first attempt/code, the `$current_user_id` is undefined - maybe you meant to do `$current_user_id = $current_user->ID; //get the user id` ? But you could just do `update_user_meta( $current_user->ID , ... )`. And in your second attempt, that `$user_id` is an object, not a user ID. And actually, to get just the current user's ID, you can use `get_current_user_id()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ. So I should do ````$user_id = get_current_user_id()````?

Comment: Yes, you can try doing that.

Comment: @SallyCJ, I tried it. Unfortunatly, it wll still not work. You can see the new code I used in my question (second code block)

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_current_user_id() );` show? Where did you put the code? In a function? Is it hooked to any hook (e.g. `init`)? Can you show the full or more of your code?

Comment: @SallyCJ. Sure, wait I will include all of the code in my question. var_dump( get_current_user_id() ); shows int(3). Which is correct because my user id is 3

Comment: @SallyCJ, no I did not use any hook.

Comment: Actually, when you said "unable to make it work", what exactly is not working? The meta value isn't getting saved to the database? What's the output of `var_dump( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() ) );` ?

Comment: The output of ````var_dump( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() ) );```` is ````int(3)````. The ````user_login```` in the database is not updated to Jimbo. @SallyCJ

Comment: You do know that `update_user_meta()` updates the WordPress users *meta* table, which (the name) defaults to `wp_usermeta` if the table prefix is `wp_`? I mean, are you actually trying to update the users table (`wp_users`), or more specifically the `user_login` field/column in that table?

Comment: I am trying to change to change the user_login field/column in the wpex_users table. So the user_login name of user (in this case with id 3) has to be changed to Jimbo. @SallyCJ